# Mutual TLS with Apache proxy to Tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat, ssl, reverse-proxy, mutual-authentication

The setup I am working with involves an Apache server acting as a proxy to a tomcat server which serves several web applications. I have enabled mutual TLS on apache and I can successfully connect to one of my tomcat web applications and verify the client certificate. However, I want to take this one step further... At the moment in my ssl.conf I have a default HTTPS VirtualHost configuration which looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
   ....
   SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile /path/to/www_yoursite_com.crt
   ....
   #other SSL options...
</VirtualHost>
```

In my modproxy.conf I have a configuration as follows:

```
ProxyPass /webApp1 https://localhost:1234/webApp1
ProxyPassReverse /webApp1 https://localhost:1234/webApp1

ProxyPass /webApp2 https://localhost:1234/webApp2
ProxyPassReverse /webApp2 https://localhost:1234/webApp2
```

where 1234 is the https port configured on a connector element on tomcat's server.xml file.

Let's assume that I only want mTLS for webApp1, the problem with this configuration is that I need a client cert on my browser even if I am accessing webApp2 so in other words I want to enable mTLS only for one web application. Even better, I would like to enable mTLS for a specific URL within my web application (is this even possible??), so for example I want mTLS required when someone hits https://myserver.com/webApp1/test/mtlsEndpoint but not on https://myserver.com/webApp1/test/otherEndpoint.

Is it possible to achieve this with another VirtualHost config for SSL on my ssl.conf ? I am going to test this tomorrow (trying to achieve this with another VirtualHost config that will proxy mTLS to my webApp1) but thought I should ask here as well to avoid trial and error and reinventing the wheel maybe this is easier than I am thinking ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just need separate SSL directives for `webApp1` and `webApp2`. SSL directives can be configured in Apache right down to the directory level.